# does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping issue in Laravel Composer after updating composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Before updating the composer the project had fine. after the update, composer showing the following message in laravel 5.8 whit hit `composer dump-autoload` command.

> does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

How can I solve this?

skipping directory with the message:

> Class App\Http\Requests\Academic\Faculty\AddValidation located in C:/xampp/htdocs/larvel-project/collegeaccounting/app\Request\Academic\Faculty\AddValidation.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

composer auto load:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Conf\\": "config/",
            "Model\\": "model/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
```

[image]

Comment: you can solve it by making that class comply with PSR4 autoloading ... in the correct directory with the correct names, etc  .... the namespace is `App\Requests` but you have them in `app/Request` ... this does not match, the folder would have to be named `Requests` .. you should look into what PSR4 autoloading is

Comment: The path does not match in two ways: `app` vs `App`. And the namespace starts with  `App\Http\Requests` vs the path being `app\Request` (missing `Http`, and plural namespace `Requests` converted into singular pathname `Request`).